# drop rows with conditions

Tags: r, string

I would like to remove some rows containing specific characters at a certain position

Example

```
df<- data.frame(x = c("HFr2c", "HFr3e", "HRr2a", "Hrr2b"))
```

You will see a small `r` at second position. Now I only want to remove rows containing `r` at third position.

I was trying to use the function `str_sub` to remove it

```
df %>% filter(x != str_sub("r", start = 3, end = 3))
```

However, it did not remove those rows I want.

Anyone can help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

try `data.table` package to filter in realy easy way

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[!grepl("r", substr(x,3,3),ignore.case = FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(x, '^..r', negate = TRUE))
```